# MS Word Autocorrect entry automation with delphi from msaccess stored data

Tags: delphi

Help! I am trying to automate autocorrect entries that are in rich text format stored in access db. 
It works fine if I use autocorrect.entries.Add but fails with autocorrect.entries.AddRichText. Look at the code below. I would appreciate your help!

```
procedure TfrmdxForm.acBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
DXRANGE, DXWORD: oleVariant;
DXSTR: STRING;

begin
DXWORD := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
DXWORD.Visible := FALSE;
MyADODataSet.First;
while NOT MyADODataSet.Eof do
begin
DXRANGE:= MyADODataSet.FieldByName('DX').Text; 
// here is where it fails … I don't know how to change this to a range
DXSTR := MyADODataSet.FieldByName('DXCODE').Text;
DXWORD.Autocorrect.Entries.AddRichText(DXSTR, DXRANGE);
// here it works if I use Add but it fails with AddRichText
MyADODataSet.Next;
end;
DXWORD.QUIT;

end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read carefully the documentation on MSDN regarding Add and AddRichText?

Add has two Parameters

1. Name - the Name of these entry
2. Value - the autoreplacement text

AddRichText has also two Parameters

1. Name - same as above
2. Range - A Selection Range inside the document with the desired replacement text

So you have to place the desired text inside the document, then select it (or try to get it in a range e.g. Paragraph) and after that you can use the AddRichText method